# Grepping or awking an LDAP record: how?

Tags: shell

I'm not an experienced shell scripter, so I'm hoping for some expert help!

We use the following command in a for loop that cycles through UIDs:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-purple.example.com -b ou=People,dc=example,dc=com uid=jdoe
```

This command yields a record such as this:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=People,dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: uid=jdoe
# requesting: ALL
#

# jdoe, people, example.com
dn: uid=jdoe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
cn: John Doe
homeDirectory: /afs/rats.example.com/users/t/jdoe
loginShell: /bin/bash
objectClass: posixAccount
uid: jdoe
uidNumber: 9239
gidNumber: 100002

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

What I'd like to do is be able to grep or awk (or whatever) to then generate the 'cn','uid', and 'uidNumber' on the same row, I.e.

```
John Doe, jdoe, 9239
```

I'm not sure what tool can be used to create this, however.

Thanks in advance your your help!

Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, easy with awk. Given that you say this is running in a loop, I'm sketching in a solution with a basic loop, that may or maynot match what you're doing. Hopefully you'll see how to adapt to your exact needs.

```
while read ou dc1 dc2 uid ; do
    dapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-purple.example.com -b ou="$ou",dc1="$dc1",dc="$dc2" uid="$uid" \
    | gawk -F":" '
        $1=="cn" { cn = $2; sub(/^  */,"", cn); next}
        $1=="uid" { uid = $2; sub(/^  */,"", uid);next}
        $1=="uidNumber" { uidNumber = $2; sub(/^  */,"", uidNumber );next}

        # ... etc
        END {
           printf("%s,%s,%s\n", cn,uid,uidNumber)
        }           
    '
done < /path/to/ldap_lookup.lst
```

**output**

```
John Doe,jdoe,9239
```

(Using your sample record above as input)

If for some reason you want the leading spaces in the records, take out the `sub()` cmds.

I don't have ldapsearch to test with. If you get error messages, gawk is pretty good about showing where the problem is, and if it's not exactly where it identifies the problem spot, then it's usually before that. Post error messages as comments and I'll see what I can do.

IHTH

Comment: your solution is intriguing because it's quite portable. How could I wrap my for loop around your solution?        `#!/bin/sh
for i in /tmp/list.dat; 
do ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-purple.example.com -b ou=People,dc=crm,dc=example,dc=com uid=$i ; 
done`

Comment: @doug ; Sorry I don't follow. Please edit your post to include example data that is in your `/list/list.dat` file. Is it only values for `uid`? If so, then change my read line to `while read uid ; do` ... and eliminate the processing for ou, etc. Put another way, my version should be able to process your file. Are you saying that the `dc=` values never change? Note that for and while loops are pretty interchangeable, but for reading values from cfg/list files, `while read var1 var2 varN ...; od` is almost always better. Good luck.

Comment: actually I think it's just a newbie syntax error that's causing this to fail.    I'm getting the following error:  `stack-test.sh: line 8: "while read ou dc1 dc2 uid ; do"`   My script reads a list of UIDs only:  `#!/bin/sh
ou="People"
dc1="example"
dc2="com"

for i in /tmp/list.dat; 
       
while read ou dc1 dc2 uid ; do

    ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-purple.example.com -b ou="$ou",dc1="$dc1",dc="$dc2" uid="$i" \
    | gawk -F":"   <your code here>      
    '
done < /tmp/ldap-out.out`

Comment: I had assumed that your /tmp/list.dat had individual records with values `example<T>com<T>uid`, hence the assignment of variables from the `while read line dc1 dc2 uid; do ...` . The var names can be any name, ie `mydc1 mydc2 myuid` or what ever you like AND there only need to be variables listed for the values you expect to be in your input file. Please reread my previous comment, as you don't need two loops (based on what you have presented). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "gidNumber: [0-9]+" ; FS = "\n" ; OFS=","}
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
       if ($i ~ "^cn: ") { cn=gensub("^cn: ","","g",$i) }
       if ($i ~ "^uidNumber: ") { uidNum=gensub("^uidNumber: ","","g",$i) }
       if ($i ~ "^uid: ") { uid=gensub("^uid: ","","g",$i) }
      }
  if ( cn > "" && uid > "" && uidNum > "" ) {
       print cn, uid, uidNum
      }
  cn="" ; uid="" ; uidNum=""
}' INPUTFILE
```

Might work for you. [See it in action at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/e4JFx) (I have added one more record for testing).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, I'll try all of them!

Before I saw your replies, I scrapped the following together, that while ugly, does the trick:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-purple.example.com -b ou=People,dc=example,dc=com uid=$i | awk -F': ' '/uid:/ {ORS=",";print $2} /uidNumber/ {ORS="\n";print $2} /cn/ {ORS=",";split ($2,fields,"-"); print fields[1]}'
```